# Why doesn't "cp -a" also copy and preserve all git files?

Tags: git, copy, tar, cp

Because of some directory changes, I need to copy my local development directory to a new location. This development directory is using git to sync to a external git repo. Recently there were some new file changes made that was not committed and pushed to that external repo. My wish is to just copy everything to a new directory and continue git'ing where I left of.

In original directory:

```
~/original_dir $ git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
    modified:   ...

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../README.md
    ...

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After doing `cp -a ~/original_dir ~/new_dir`, I simply get:

```
~/new_dir $ git status

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Inspection shows that .git is missing from root directory of copy. This is quite concerning as I have been using `cp -a` for backups. Which mean that `cp -a` cannot be trusted to copy everything. (According to man pages, `-a` is "same as `-dR --preserve=all`".)

**What is the proper cp command to have an exact snapshot of that directory?**

---

**NOTE:** Using `tar -cf old_dir.tar old_dir` and then extracting this, **does** yield an exact directory copy, that can also be used to continue your git operations as you left off.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/61611

Comment: @1615903 - Looks like the OP is already doing the correct thing with respect to that, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the important bit is that the destination directory must not exist, OP does not specify if that is the case here. But regardless of that, the question is clearly off topic for SO since it's a "how do I use my operating system" -question.

Comment: @1615903 Yes, destination directory doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to links in OP comments, I think I found two answers.

(1) Apparently my Bash has the `dotglob` shell option off by default, it need to be **on**.

```
$ shopt 
...
dotglob         off
...
```

(2) A very subtle trick is to specify a trailing dot in the copy command, and that the destination directory already exists:

```
cp -a old_dir/. new_dir/
```

Second one I still need to test.

Comment: Unless you have `cp` aliased, `dotglob` should have no effect on `cp -a dir`, only on `cp -a dir/*` (because `dir` has no glob in it while `dir/*` has one glob expression).

Comment: I've confirmed option (2) works for me on Linux without `dotglob`